# Flutter navigating back to an existing instance of a screen

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-navigation

My apologies if this has been asked before, but I my searches couldn't find quite the right answer.

I'm new to Flutter and am building an app with Drawer navigation like this:

```
<Map Link>

<Signup Form Link>

<Login Form Link>
```

If someone is in the map and looks around, places markers, etc. then opens the drawer and navigates to another page, everything works as expected with `Navigator.push()`.  However, my initial thought was if they opened the drawer again and tapped "Map" then it would bring them back to the map screen in the same state as when they left it, however it loads a new instance.  If I then use the back button it goes back to the previous page and then to the original map instance.

My questions is how do I get Flutter to recognize that there is already an existing state of a screen and use that rather than creating a new one?

I am implementing `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` in the Map class so I have the state saving itself, I just need Flutter to use that rather than creating a new one.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can first try `Navigator.pop(context);` or more advanced `popUntil()` like [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html) if you use named routes.

Does any of that works for you?

Comment: `.pop()` won't work most likely if we are multiple pages "deep" in the stack, but I didn't know `.popUntil()` existed.  That's interesting, but I can't explicitly call this because it may be the first instance so a previous doesn't exist.

Comment: You could pop it until first route index like this `Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);`  Another option would be to play around with `.canPop()` or write a custom flag to check what route you are at.

Comment: @MartinM where do I get the `'/login'` from the `ModalRoute.withName('/login')`?